# Failed install Bettercap /usr/local/bin/bettercap: line 9: require: command not found

Tags: encoding, binary, ruby-2.3

Good evening community

I hope you can help me, I am trying to install bettercap on my kali linux, but I am getting the following errors

/usr/local/bin/bettercap: line 9: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/bettercap: line 11: version: command not found
/usr/local/bin/bettercap: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /usr/local/bin/bettercap: line 15:`  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pOl8.png)

I have not found much information, enter the bettercap file and the following is displayed. How can I solve it? Any ideas? I hope you can help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKLfA.png)